# Copy file between S3 buckets cross-account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have AWS account (`account_a`) which has S3 bucket (`bkt_a`) containing file: `file1`.

The account has access_key (`access_key_A`) and secret_key (`secret_key_a`).

I have also AWS account (`account_b`) which has bucket (`bkt_b`).

The account has access_key (`access_key_b`) and secret_key (`secret_key_b`).

I would like to copy `file1` from `bkt_a` to `file1_processed` in `bkt_b`.

I would like to do it using **python boto3 only** as I don't want to use shell commands (OS command with CLI copy).

How do I do it? How to use the two access keys and secret keys when calling the boto3 S3 client/resource ?

I would be happy to get some code lines.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two separate s3 clients, one for each account, and interface with them according to your requirements.

```
import boto3

client_a = boto3.client(
  's3',
  aws_access_key_id='<access_key_A>',
  aws_secret_access_key='<secret_key_a>'
)
client_b = boto3.client(
  's3',
  aws_access_key_id='<access_key_b>',
  aws_secret_access_key='<secret_key_b>'
)

// client_a read from bkt_a
// client_b write to bkt_b
```

Of course, it is important to remember that the credentials you are using are for an IAM user/role with an appropriate S3 policy attached.

**NOTE** -- It is generally a poor decision to place credentials directly in your code, especially if you are putting the code into a shared source code repository.  I recommend the values are either passed provided to your python script, or read from a secured location.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting, this solution is for download + upload, not "copy" (which occurs within S3) -- but copy isn't possible unless *one* set of credentials has the necessary permissions to access *both* buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Arriving after the battle but in case you need to transfer large objects in a container with limited memory, here is how to stream it:

```python
src_bucket = boto3.Session(...).resource('s3').Bucket('###')
dst_bucket = boto3.Session(...).resource('s3').Bucket('###')

for summary in src_bucket.objects.all():
    print(f'Copying {summary.key}...')
    stream = src_bucket.Object(summary.key).get()['Body']
    dst_bucket.upload_fileobj(stream, summary.key)
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to copy these objects is to use a set of credentials that have permission to Read from `bkt_a` and write to `bkt_b`. This would enable use of `copy_object()`, which will copy the file directly between the two buckets without having to Download and Upload.

The simplest implementation would be:

- Use a set of credentials (eg IAM Role) from `account_b` that has permission to write to `bkt_b`
- Add a **bucket policy** to `bkt_a` that permits these credentials to read from `bkt_a` (this can be a temporary policy, which can be removed after the copy).
- Iterate through the objects and copy them from `bkt_a` to `bkt_b`

  - Specify `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'` to grant ownership of the new objects to `bkt_b` (might not be necessary if using `account_b` credentials, but certainly necessary if using `account_a` credentials)

If you cannot arrange for one set of credentials to have both A-Read and B-Write permissions, then you will need to download and upload each object, which is sub-optimal.